# Parsing JSON into Oracle type with nested table

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

Is there a way to make this Oracle query more optimal? Ideally without selecting from the same JSON_TABLE twice.

```
SELECT to_dncl_verification(status_code   => t.status,
                            d_valid_from  => to_date(t.d_valid_from, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                            d_valid_to    => to_date(t.d_valid_to, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                            category_list => CAST(
                                                  MULTISET (SELECT tc.category, CASE WHEN tc.allowed = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                                                              FROM JSON_TABLE(l_clob_response, '$'
                                                                   COLUMNS NESTED PATH '$.categories[*]'
                                                                     COLUMNS (category VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.category',
                                                                              allowed  VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.allowed')
                                                                   ) tc 
                                                            ) AS tc_dncl_category
                                                     )
                               )
      INTO y_verification_result
      FROM JSON_TABLE(l_clob_response, '$'
                      COLUMNS status       VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.status',
                              d_valid_from VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.dateValidFrom',
                              d_valid_to   VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.dateValidTo'
                      ) t;
```

Let's consider that types are created as follows:

```
create or replace type to_dncl_category is object (
  category_code   varchar2(20),
  is_allowed      number
);

create or replace type tc_dncl_category is table of to_dncl_category;

create or replace type to_dncl_verification is object (
  status_code          varchar2(20),
  d_valid_from         date,
  d_valid_to           date,
  category_list        tc_dncl_category  
);
```

Also let's consider variable l_clob_response is JSON with following data:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "status": "PARTIALLY_BLOCKED",
    "dateOfCheck": "2023-01-01",
    "dateValidFrom": "2023-05-15",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "category": "category ABC",
            "allowed": true,
            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T10:47:19.745Z",
            "recordVersion": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "category": "category DEF",
            "allowed": false,
            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T10:47:19.745Z",
            "recordVersion": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "category": "category GHI",
            "allowed": true,
            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T10:47:19.745Z",
            "recordVersion": 0
        }
    ],
    "dateValidTo": "2023-05-30",
    "recordVersion": 0
}
```

My query works and returns an expected result, I just feel like it could be more optimal.

Answer (score 2):

One variant is to extract the `categories` array in the outer query and then use that in the inner query. You would need to test each version and check which is more performant.

```sql
DECLARE
  l_clob_response CLOB := '{
    "id": "123",
    "status": "PARTIALLY_BLOCKED",
    "dateOfCheck": "2023-01-01",
    "dateValidFrom": "2023-05-15",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "category": "category ABC",
            "allowed": true,
            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T10:47:19.745Z",
            "recordVersion": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "category": "category DEF",
            "allowed": false,
            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T10:47:19.745Z",
            "recordVersion": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "category": "category GHI",
            "allowed": true,
            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T10:47:19.745Z",
            "recordVersion": 0
        }
    ],
    "dateValidTo": "2023-05-30",
    "recordVersion": 0
}';
   y_verification_result to_dncl_verification;
BEGIN
  SELECT to_dncl_verification(
           status_code   => t.status,
           d_valid_from  => to_date(t.d_valid_from, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           d_valid_to    => to_date(t.d_valid_to, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
           category_list => CAST(
                              MULTISET (
                                SELECT tc.category,
                                       CASE WHEN tc.allowed = 'true'
                                       THEN 1
                                       ELSE 0
                                       END
                                FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                                         t.categories,
                                         '$[*]'
                                         COLUMNS 
                                           category VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.category',
                                           allowed  VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.allowed'
                                         ) tc 
                              ) AS tc_dncl_category
                            )
         )
  INTO   y_verification_result
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           l_clob_response,
           '$'
           COLUMNS
             status       VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.status',
             d_valid_from VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.dateValidFrom',
             d_valid_to   VARCHAR2(255) PATH '$.dateValidTo',
             categories   CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.categories'
           ) t;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    y_verification_result.category_list.COUNT
  );
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WoWS21Ip)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has default JSON to Object deserialization recursively based on the matched names. See [18.3 Using JSON_VALUE To Instantiate a User-Defined Object Type Instance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/function-JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-622170D8-7BAD-4F5F-86BF-C328451FC3BE) section of `JSON_VALUE` function dosc for details.

In order to map your JSON data to your object type you have to reshape the JSON document with, for example, [`JSON_TRANSFORM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/JSON_TRANSFORM.html#GUID-DD2A821B-C688-4310-81B5-5F45090B9366) function:

- Remove all extra attributes that are not mapped to object attributes.
- Rename all used attributes to match object attributes.
- As long as `boolean` JSON datatype [is mapped to](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/clauses-used-in-functions-and-conditions-for-json.html#GUID-21FE887D-5D7B-43BB-A1A8-B26B8924B290) `varchar2` or `clob`, you need to either replace `true/false` with `1/0` (which I didn't manage to work with `set` modification) or use `varchar2` object attribute for this.

Combining all together, there's a query:

```
select
 json_value(
  json_transform(
    val,

    keep '$.status', '$.dateValidFrom','$.dateValidTo',
      '$.categories[*].category', '$.categories[*].allowed',

    -- set '$.categories[*].allowed?(@ == true)' = 1 ignore on missing,
    -- set '$.categories[*].allowed?(@ == false)' = 0 ignore on missing,

    
    rename '$.status' = 'status_code' error on missing,
    rename '$.dateValidFrom' = 'd_valid_from' error on missing,
    rename '$.dateValidTo' = 'd_valid_to' error on missing,
    rename '$.categories[*].category' = 'category_code' error on missing,
    rename '$.categories[*].allowed' = 'is_allowed' ignore on missing,
    rename '$.categories' = 'category_list' error on missing
  )
  , '$' returning to_dncl_verification) as res
from sample
```

```
RES(STATUS_CODE, D_VALID_FROM, D_VALID_TO, CATEGORY_LIST(CATEGORY_CODE, IS_ALLOWED))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-----------------------------
TO_DNCL_VERIFICATION('PARTIALLY_BLOCKED', '15.05.23', '30.05.23', TC_DNCL_CATEGORY(TO_DNCL_CATEGORY('category ABC', 'true'), TO_DNCL_CATEGORY('category DEF', 'false'), TO_DNCL_CATEGORY('category GHI', 'true')))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VoLMvuLl)